# Programming Theory: Shuffling a 2D Array

Tags: arrays, complexity-theory, theory, shuffle, computation-theory

Me and a friend are mulling over an **interesting** Computer Science question.

---

You have a simple **2D Array**:

```
[  1,  2,  3,  4 ]
[  5,  6,  7,  8 ]
[  9, 10, 11, 12 ]
[ 13, 14, 15, 16 ]
```

Now take this array and **shuffle all the elements** in the array:

```
[ 11,  5, 14, 10 ]
[  8,  2,  4, 16 ]
[ 15,  1,  3, 13 ]
[  6, 12,  9,  7 ]
```

A fairly simple concept at first. However, what if we take it **one more step**? Now, **shuffle the original array** such that *no* elements of the new array are next to an item they were adjacent to in the **original array** in a cardinal direction.

Our first shuffle **fails** as 1 is next to 2 and was also next to 2 in the original array.

Here is a **working** example:

```
[  7, 16, 13,  2 ]
[ 14,  3,  5,  8 ]
[  9,  1,  4, 11 ]
[ 12, 10, 15,  6 ]
```

Still not *too* bad. Now to the **real** question!

Shuffle the **original array** again such that *no* elements of the array are next to an element they were adjacent to in either cardinal directions **or via diagonals**.

Our working example **fails** since 1 is next to 5 diagonally and was next to 5 in the original array.

### Some Thoughts:

1. Can an array even be determined?
2. Does it depend on the size of the array?
3. Does the array need to be symmetrical?
4. Does the array need to have an even / odd amount of elements?
5. Does a solution hold for all arrays of size **M** by **N**?
6. If there exists a solution, what would be the running time to find the new array?

What do you think?

**EDIT**

I am surprised to find my question closed as "off topic". According to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) if my question "...generally covers a specific programming problem..." then it is allowed to be asked and is not "off-topic".

The bottom-line question I was asking is:

> "Can you take a 2D array and shuffle it so no members will be next to each other in the new array, including diagonals".

Is that not a good programming question? I feel strongly my question should not be closed.

Comment: Answer to #2 is clearly yes.  A 2x2 array has no solution.

Comment: A 3x3 array has no solution either, since the middle number is originally adjacent to all other numbers.

Comment: A simple 90 degree rotate will probably do what you want. Elements will not be adjacent horizontally with regards to the original, not will they be diagonal. If the array is still read in the original manner, it is effectively shuffled.

Comment: This breaks my brain a little.  I'm gonna puzzle over it for a while.  I take it that the adjacency rules do *not* wrap around the left/right and top/bottom, given the (2,6) pair as an example.

Comment: The minimum size is 4x4. My answer will only work if you are applying this to a real world situation. If you are looking for a "shuffled to the eye" solution, this is much more complex.

Comment: @IanC As far as being adjacent, we meant if 1 is next to 2, 6, and 5 in the original array then in the new array 1 cannot be next to 2, 6, or 5 either adjacent or diagonally.

Comment: In general, after musing a bit more it seems the solution may reside in having a large enough array as an item can only have a max of 8 neighbors so the larger array gives us more room to find a solution. Maybe the true question is: "What is the smallest array with a solution to the problem."

Comment: @paddy Yes, we were not considering the wrap-around adjacency. So some elements have less neighbors than others.

Comment: I worked out a simple algorithm that works perfectly for a 4x4 matrix. Meets all your criteria. But, is this homework? Are you looking for an algorithm?

Comment: @IanC I would be interested to see your algorithm. I guess this question does come off as a HW problem, but I assure it is simply a thought experiment that came from some conversation over dinner. I am working on a CS degree, so coming up with this conundrum over dinner is not that abnormal. :)

Comment: Why was this closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Can an array even be determined?
```

- Sure, you can use a transformation Rn -> RN via transposing to edges.

> 2.Does it depend on the size of the array?

- You can't do it for MxM <= 3, so Yes.

> 3.Does the array need to be symmetrical?

- It depends *

> Does the array need to have an even / odd amount of elements?

- It depends *

> 5.Does a solution hold for all arrays of size M by N?

- It depends *

> 6.If there exists a solution, what would be the running time to find the new array?

Running time could be `O(N^2)` using a simple transformation (considering though as `O(1)`).

- This depends on considering duplicates as part of the solution ([a bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)) or not (a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29)).

Now as for the algorithm itself. Although this seems like a nice way to brain exercise it sounds more like a homework so why don't you try something and ask for specifics.